# drag & drop not working when page loaded in a parent div

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have an application that takes a list of 32 names and allows them to be dragged and dropped into nine separate divs and then to be dragged and dropped between those nine divs.

When the page is executed stand alone, it works flawlessly.

However, when the page is loaded into a parent div the functionality goes to hell.  I can drag and drop one time only.  When I attempt to drag/drop a name from one of the nine divs, to another div, I can drag it okay but when it is dropped it returns to its original position.

Here is the drag/drop code

```
$(document).ready (function (){

$('.draggable').draggable(
{revert:'invalid'}
)



$('.droppable').droppable({
    tolerance:'intersect',
    drop: function (event,ui){
    $(this).addClass ('person');
    $(this).append ('<p class="draggable">'+$(ui.draggable).text()+'</p>');
    $(ui.draggable).remove();
    $('.draggable').draggable({
      revert:'invalid',    
  });
```

}
}

And here's the simple code to load the page into the parent div

```
$('button.worklist').click (function (){
   $('div#content').load ('worklist.php');
})
```

So the question becomes, is there anything extra I need to do to get UI events to function properly when they page the act upon is loaded into a div?

Answer (score 0):

After you load the content from `worklist.php` into `div#content`, you need to re-initialize the drag and drop functions.

The drag and drop functions are initialized in `document.ready()` for only the items that are currently on the page.  If you add more items to the page, you need to re-initialize the drag and drop methods.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that's the answer.  Maybe I wasn't clear initially.  draggable and droppable are **not** initialized on the page that loads them into div#content, they are initialized on the page that is loaded.  I have tried initializing them after worklist is loaded and nothing changes.