# Simple Drag and Drop works stand-alone but not in a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a little drag and drop script (HTML5/Javascript) which functions correctly in a [stand-alone](http://wip.bespoke-webwork.com/DnD/index.php) page. However when I integrate it into a [web page](http://wip.bespoke-webwork.com/Anna/contact.php) it doesn't allow dragging (Black circle with diagonal stripe when attempting to drag).
I have simulated the web-page's additional javascript in the stand-alone to rule out javascript conflict. I'm just not seeing why this happens! Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Comment: You have an error on your website : _Object #<Object> has no method 'draggable'_.

Comment: @matewka - any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using two jQuery versions :

1. v1.3.2
2. v1.9.1

Remove the v1.3.2 and it will work

Comment: Thank you I have removed #1 and also the modernizr-1.5.min.js duplication. However the problem remains - I rather think the answer lies in the error pointed out by matewka and am ignorant about how he discovered the error (my javascript sucks). If someone could point me to the tool used to find this error I would be most grateful!

Comment: Press F12 this will open dev tools in chrome. Then click on console tab then click on error this will redirect to at the error

Comment: i think you have removed #2 not #1

Comment: Having used the Chrome Dev Tools I am not able to get the same error flag as @matewka Object #<Object> has no method 'draggable'. However, on the web-page script I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" - referring to this section in the script...<script>
$(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ revert: "valid" }); So I'm afraid that the solution is no clearer to me ...

Comment: I see that @Dave Davis had a similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716649/drag-drop-not-working-when-page-loaded-in-a-parent-div?rq=1 and it seems not to have been resolved...